# Formulas for the entries of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

> $$A = \begin{pmatrix}2&2\\ -4&8\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Find formulas for the entries of $A^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

I think I know the method to solve this problem but I am only getting half of the entries correct in the final matrix. This is what I have done so far:

Eigenvalues are $6$ and $4$. Eigenvectors for those eigenvalues are $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ respectively.

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&1\\ \:\:1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ (I combined both eigenvectors)

$$P^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}-2&2\\ \:\:2&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}6&0\\ \:0&4\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B^n = \begin{pmatrix}6^n&0\\ \:0&4^n\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A^n = P^{-1}B^{n}P$$

$$A^n = \begin{pmatrix}-2^n\cdot \:3^n+2^{2n+1}&-3^n\cdot \:2^{n+1}+2^{2n+1}\\ 2^n\cdot \:3^n-4^n&3^n\cdot \:2^{n+1}-4^n\end{pmatrix}$$

My top left and bottom right entries seem to be correct but my top right and bottom left entries still appear to be wrong. I have doubled checked and can't seem to find anything.

Would anyone happen to know why?

Thank you!

Comment: $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2^{2 n+1}-6^n & -4^n+6^n \\
 2^{2 n+1}-2^{n+1} 3^n & 2^{n+1} 3^n-4^n \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ Note the simplifications.

Comment: Yes! That is the correct answer! Do you happen to know where I went wrong? I want to avoid this mistake in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Just a general question: Why are you allowing a fractional entry in one of your eigenvalues?

Comment: @imranfat I am sorry I do not quite understand what you mean. My eigenvalues are 6 and 4...

Comment: Sorry, I mean in your eigenvector......It is not against the law, but it isn't common.

Comment: @imranfat Oh. I thought when I calculated it that that was the eigenvector. Perhaps it was there I made a mistake. Do you happen to know what the eigenvector should be instead, if the one I have calculated is wrong?

Comment: There's no such thing as “the” eigenvector. Any non-zero multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue.

Comment: Instead of entries $1/2$ and $1$ you could have chosen $1$ and $2$

Comment: The multiplication order is wrong. It must be $A^n = PB^nP^{-1}.$